# How to map a DataTable of strings to a DataTable of integers in c# using a built-in library?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, datatable, mapping, artificial-intelligence

I have a set of DataTables, each with a set of rows, and a set of columns, all strings.
I am looking for the best way(i.e.,the shortest codeLength-wise and optionally the most efficient performance-wise) to map each of these DataTables to DataTables with integer values, such that the same string will always be represented by the same integer value across all the tables, and also within the same table **(without writing my own loops/etc, as one option is to loop all over the data and create integers out of strings).**

My question is: Are there any built-in libraries in c# to perform this task by calling a method?

Assumptions: 
a) There are thousands of tables, and millions of entries in the tables. 
b) The solution could be case sensitive or insensitive.

Assuming such example:

```
DataTableInStrings1.Rows[10]["Column10"] = "val1";
DataTableInStrings2.Rows[2]["Column1"] = "val1";
```

Expected short-code:

```
DataTable dataTableInIntegers1 = LibIAmAfter.MethodIAmAfter(DataTableInStrings1)
DataTable dataTableInIntegers2 = LibIAmAfter.MethodIAmAfter(DataTableInStrings2)
```

Expected result

```
dataTableInIntegers1.Rows[10]["Column10"]=12; 
dataTableInIntegers2.Rows[2]["Column1"]=12;
```

Whereas the integer 12 could be any value. Here it is chosen randomly to illustrate the goal.

==> Another example to help with understanding the question:

```
row1InStrings: ("abc","def","abc","zxv","was","morning","def","dr","tr","uy");
row2InStrings: ("abc2","def2","abc3","zxv4","was4","morning2","def2","dr3","tr3","uy");
```

Sample result after mapping:

```
row1InIntegers: 1,2,1,3,4,5,2,6,7,8
row2InIntegers: 10,11,12,14,15,16,11,17,18,8
```

Comment: Why is there no mapping for `9` or `13`?

Comment: The integer values are put there randomly, if somethings translates to 9 or 13, they could also show up. It doesn't matter which numbers, but I am interested in a set of integers that represent the same string with the same value always.

Comment: Do you care about case sensitivity? i.e. would `"morning"` and `"Morning"` have different mappings?

Comment: We could consider it case in-sensitive for now.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a `Dictionary<string, int>` to store the cell data as the key and the mapping integer as the value.

Note that you wouldn't have to populate the mapping with the entire data set at once. As long as you're maintaining a single mapping dictionary, you can simply populate it as you access items.

Note that this will only guarantee a value for a string is unique, but not necessarily the same value on subsequent runs (since the values are based on when the id was requested and not the string itself).

Something like this static class with a private field and an access method should work (though not thread-safe):

```
public static class Mapper
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> Mapping = 
        new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public static int GetId(string value)
    {
        int result;

        if (!Mapping.TryGetValue(value, out result))
        {
            result = Mapping.Count + 1;
            Mapping.Add(value, result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

With this method, we can get the mappings as we need them, and the dictionary is populated only as necessary:

```
DataTable tbl1 = new DataTable("table1");
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col1"));
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col2"));
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col3"));
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col4"));
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col5"));
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col6"));
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col7"));
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col8"));
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col9"));
tbl1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col10"));

tbl1.Rows.Add("abc", "def", "abc", "zxv", "was", "morning", "def", "dr", "tr", "uy");
tbl1.Rows.Add("abc2", "def2", "abc3", "zxv4", "was4", "Morning", "def2", "dr3", "tr3", "uy");

// Output mappings, which populates the dictionary     
// only when needed as each mapping is requested
foreach (DataRow row in tbl1.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", 
        row.ItemArray.Select(item => Mapper.GetId(item.ToString()))));
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. This makes sense, but given the large volume of tables and rows in them, it might not be very efficient. As an alternative are you aware of any library for such mappings?

Comment: There are some hashing methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605707/how-to-uniquely-identify-a-set-of-strings-using-an-integer) that you could use.

Comment: You could also just use `row[col].ToString().GetHashCode()`, but that's not 100% guaranteed, since there are technically more than `2^32` possible strings (which is the max limit of the `int` that `GetHashCode` returns).

Comment: I've updated the answer with a method that will populate the dictionary only as item ids are requested, to prevent populating the whole thing with values that we may not need. Note that this will only guarantee a value for a string is unique, but not necessarily the same value on subsequent runs (since the values are based on when the id was requested and not the string itself).

Comment: hmm... I came across Accord.Statistics.Filter, with this method  `var codeBook1 = new Codification();DataTable tblIntegers = codeBook1.Apply( tblStrings1);`, The values are unique within one column, but not across multiple columns of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Sum the char value of each value in the row.  Notice that summing char values doesn't ensure that each value is unique.  You can have multiple ways to create the same numeric value.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void test_sum_stringchars()
    {
        string tmp = "foobar5";
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + tmp.ToCharArray().Sum(x => x));
        // 686

        tmp = "foobar6";
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + tmp.ToCharArray().Sum(x => x));
        // 687

        tmp = "goobar5";
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + tmp.ToCharArray().Sum(x => x));
        // 687

        tmp = "foocar5";
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + tmp.ToCharArray().Sum(x => x));
        // 687
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would be better if we get unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a deterministic guid to create a unique hash.  Moreover, you could just use the value itself as it's own unique hash.  I can only see this being useful if for some reason, you can't show users the original value but still want to find it in a list.  For example, an array of passwords.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void test_sum_stringchars()
    {
        string tmp = "foobar5";
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + tmp.ToCharArray().Sum(x => x));
        // 686
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + ToGuidKey(tmp));
        // 79ceeb8d

        tmp = "foobar6";
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + tmp.ToCharArray().Sum(x => x));
        // 687
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + ToGuidKey(tmp));
        // f1f08c51

        tmp = "goobar5";
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + tmp.ToCharArray().Sum(x => x));
        // 687
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + ToGuidKey(tmp));
        // f7da9f42

        tmp = "foocar5";
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + tmp.ToCharArray().Sum(x => x));
        // 687
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + ToGuidKey(tmp));
        // 7698c7ec
    }
    public static Guid ToGuid(string src)
    {
        byte[] stringbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(src);
        byte[] hashedBytes = new System.Security.Cryptography
            .SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
            .ComputeHash(stringbytes);
        Array.Resize(ref hashedBytes, 16);
        return new Guid(hashedBytes);
    }
    public static string ToGuidKey(string src)
    {
        return ToGuid(src).ToString().Split('-').First();
    }
```